# Require parameter set in controller but ModelState.IsValid is false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a view (form) which allows the user to create a new model item in my ASP.NET MVC 5 web app. There are 4 fields that need setting on this model but the form only sets 3 as the 4th is set within the controller Create action programmatically. This 4th property is a foriegn key from the AspNetUser table (the currently authenticated user)

```
public class Student
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public String FirstName{ get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public String LastName { get; set; }

    //not setting this in the view is causing an error. 
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings=false)]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserAccount { get; set; }

    // this doesn't need to be set by anyone creating a Student 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses {get;set;}
}
```

I set the view in the Create action/route like so:

```
var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();

student.UserAccount= (from t in db.Users
                        where t.Id == userID
                        select t).Single();
```

Unfortunately the ModelState.IsValid is false due to this 4th property (UserAccount) not being set in the view by the user (I can see this if I inspect the errors on the ModelState).

What is the correct solution here? Am I doing anything rookie?

Thanks

Comment: Use a view model with only the properties you need in the view.

Comment: Thanks for your rapid response. So do I create a view model which is the model duplicated minus the relations? Then in my controller do I have to create a new model and copy the values from the view model passed into it? Is this the correct work flow?

Comment: Exactly (except that it will not have a `[Key]` attribute or the `ICollection<Course> Courses` property). And you can use tools such as [automapper](http://automapper.org/) to make it easier to map to and from the view model. It would probably also have other attributes such as `[Display(Name="Last Name")]` for use in a `@LabelFor()` etc

Comment: Cool. I was going to say isn't this going to be laboursome with remapping fields from the view model (subset) to the original model, but I guess automapper is the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke also the ViewModel shouldn't have the UserAccount field, correct?

Comment: Yes, - based on your data model, it only needs `ID` (for editing existing Students). `FirstName` and `LastName`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's what I added, and I'm now using my ViewModel. ModelState.IsValid is now true :) but on db.SaveChanged() I get an error, with the InnerException:

Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Student' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.""

if i view the table code, I have:
"[ID]                INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,"

Comment: You will need to show the code in your POST method - It should be something like `var student = new Student{ FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName }; db.Students.Add(student); db.SaveChanges();` where the method parameter is `StudentVM model`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That's OK. I fixed it by creating the table/db (I didn't do  it since I turned off auto increment on the primary key ID). Thanks for your help yesterday